# how calculate UITableViewCell height seeing content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to determine cell height and place in this cell text which has images inside, for example:
some text there
image
sometext there
image
... ect.
How to implement this? Suggest pls.
Thnx.
And I want divide my paragraphs in individual cells like this:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want to GET the height of the cell, or do you want to calculate the height of the content that you will put into the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the content is dynamic, one way to do it is to calculate the height of the cell ahead of heightForRowAtIndexPath (or equivalent method) being called and store those values in an array.

```
-(void)calculateCellHeights:(NSArray *)contentArray
{
    self.heightArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: contentArray.count];
    for( MyCellContent *content in contentArray )
    {
        CGFloat totalHeight = 0;
        totalHeight += content.image.size.height;
        CGSize titleSize = [content.title sizeWithFont:self.myTitleFont];
        totalHeight += titleSize.height;
        CGSize textContentSize = [content.textContent sizeWithFont:self.myTextContentFont];
        totalHeight += textContentSize.height;
        [self.heightArray addObject:@(totalHeight)];
    }
}


-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
    return self.heightArray[[indexPath.row floatValue]];
}
```

This is assuming only one section and the use of regular text strings instead of NSAttributedStrings, and doesn't handle padding between interface elements but you get the picture.